# Trabalhando com Git no dia a dia com dois computadores diferentes

Tags: git

Tenho dois locais de trabalho onde trabalho em um projeto onde uso o controle de versão GIT. Em meus estudos já aprendi algumas coisas sobre o GIT usando o BitBucket.

Vamos pensar no seguinte cenário:

- Meu branch para deploy é o "master".
- Sempre que vou desenvolver estarei em um branch "dev".
- Computador Casa.
- Computador Escritório.

Estou trabalhando de casa em uma primeira melhoria e para isso crio pela primeira vez o branch "dev".

```
git branch dev
git checkout dev
```

Ok, fiz as melhorias, fiz os commits no branch dev e agora vou mandar tudo para o bit bucket (lembrando que estou no branch dev)

```
git push origin dev
```

Mandei minhas alterações pro Bit Bucket e agora vou ter que ir pro Escritório trabalhar de la.

Chegando no escritório eu faço o clone do meu repositório e em um primeiro momento ele vai vir vazio já que lá estarei no branch master. Então dou o comando para ver todos os branch

```
git branch -a
```

e tenho como resultado

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/dev
```

Então crio um branch no computador do escritório baseado no branch remoto dev

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

Faço as alterações do meu projeto pelo computador do escritório, dou commit nessas melhorias e mando pro servidor para o branch dev

```
git push origin dev
```

Agora estou voltando para casa e vou continuar a trabalhar no projeto. Então dou o comando git pull para baixar as últimas alterações. Só que eu já tenho no computador de casa o branch dev. Então eu faço o seguinte:

```
git ckeckout -b dev_escritorio origin/dev
```

Ok, agora tenho a versão neste branch (dev_escritorio) com as melhorias que fiz por lá. Só que quero continuar as melhorias pelo meu branch dev então eu faria:

```
git checkout dev
git merge dev_escritorio
```

Bom é isso, eu queria saber se esse é mesmo a melhor maneira quando você tem que trabalhar com dois computadores diferentes usando git, branch, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você complicou-se a partir deste ponto:

> Agora estou voltando para casa e vou continuar a trabalhar no projeto. Então dou o comando git pull para baixar as últimas alterações. Só que eu já tenho no computador de casa o branch dev. Então eu faço o seguinte...

Basta você dar sequência no desenvolvimento, apenas atualizando sua branch local:

```
git ckeckout dev;
git pull;
```

Depois fazer o `push` para a origin e continuar este ciclo, pull -> commit -> push

**Entretanto,**
recomendo um fluxo mais avançado com o uso de branchs tópicasm como você encontrará exemplificado no capítulo [Branching Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows#Long-Running-Branches) e o uso do `hack` e `ship` mas isto você deixa mais para frente em seus estudos :)

[image: Branching Workflows]

Fonte da imagem: git-scm.com

Comment: Então se eu der um git pull quando meu branch atual é o "dev" ele baixaria do repositório somente as alterações desse branch?

Comment: @rodrigoum exatamente. Entretanto, aconselho o estudo do uso de branchs tópicas, e de um fluxo mais avançado (complementarei minha resposta falando sobre este fluxo)

Comment: Se na hora do pull o git disser que não sabe qual branch pegar, use `git pull origin dev`. @rodrigoum

Comment: @gpupo muito obrigado pelas informações. Como é bom ter um histórico de tudo que fiz :D

Answer (score 0):

Sugeriria utilizar a estrutura de git flow.
Você teria a branch master que é exclusiva para deploy
Branch develop para ir recebendo as features conforme for finalizando cada nova funcionalidade
Então tanto em casa como no trabalho você daria um publish nas funcionalidades para poder trabalhar nos dois locais de forma mais organizada.

Sugiro ver:
https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.pt_BR.html